# Stop Top Menu sticking on carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I have made this website here:    http://dijon-egg.com/Possum/

If you click on green big dot button, it takes you to page2. My problem is I can't figure and fix the menu being too big on page 2 or change view of carousel on page 2 so full carousel can show to us and top menu not sticking out onto carousel.

Comment: Please provide some code for us to work with

Comment: I don't know how to use this code page and it has a lot of coding. Can't you do a view source ?

Comment: You need to provide some code and write more about the exact problem and what you expect to get

Comment: Can you do not do view point